# PHP Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php

Everytime I execute the code below, I get this error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133955562 bytes) in /home/vhosts/schoolvids.nl/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/home.php on line 100`

Line 100: `$response .= substr($string,0, stripos($string,"http://")).$url;`

```
$query = "SELECT youtube_id FROM video WHERE beschrijving = '' LIMIT 1";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    //$beschrijving = sqlesc(formatYtDescr($data['youtube_id']));
                    $json_output = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$data['youtube_id']."?v=2&alt=json");
                    $json = json_decode($json_output, true);
                    $string = $json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];
                    $string = preg_replace("/\n/", " &nbsp;<br>",$string);
                    $string = str_replace("https://", "http://", $string);

                $response = "";
                if(stripos($string, "http://")){
                    while(stripos($string, "http://")) {
                        $link = substr($string, stripos($string, "http://"), stripos($string, " ", stripos($string,"http://")) - stripos($string, "http://"));
                        $url = "<a href=\"".$link."\" target=\"_blank\">".$link."</a>";
                        $response .= substr($string,0, stripos($string,"http://")).$url;
                        $string = substr($string, stripos($string, " ", stripos($string,"http://")));
                    }
                    $response .= $string;
                }else{
                    $response = $string;
                }
                $query = "UPDATE video SET beschrijving='$response' WHERE youtube_id = '".$data['youtube_id']."'";
                mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            }
```

When I run the code by directly inserting a value instead of receiving `youtube_id` from the database, my code works perfectly. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Infinite loop. Check your logic, especially the bit inside `while(stripos($string, "http://")) { ... }`

Comment: Infinite loop with while(stripos($string, "http://"))` just print string at the end of the loop to show the problem

Comment: No, I'm sure it's not an infinite loop. Every time the code runs, 1 part containing http:// is removed from `$string`. And the fact that de code runs  without problems when I insert a youtube_id manually proves that.. EDIT: You guys are right. Not all youtube_id's cause this error but for example this one does: frXxZ7k2y. But what should I do different to solve the problem?

Comment: My suggestion is at the end of your while loop echo $string each time which should give clues as to why `while(stripos($string, "http://"))` might be creating an infinite loop. Also, your example youtube id does not appear to be valid: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/frXxZ7k2y

Comment: @JohnMcMahon my bad. it should be frXxZ7k2yJs

Comment: got the problem ;) the final line of `$string` consisted of nothing more than a link. It kept searching for a space somewhere after http:// for like forever because it wasn't there. added a space and the end of `$string` at the beginning of my code and it works like a charm except for some sql error but I'll figure that out